# How change form alert messages on cakephp

Tags: jquery, forms, cakephp

I work on website already made by cakephp 1.3. there's a from for registration the validation alerts were in arabic language , the website owner want the alerts be in english. the form use jquery.I searched all the files to find where change the text to be in english can't find tell found this bath

app/tmp/cache/persistent/cake_core_default_en_us

i found messages in english & translated in arabic
.I replaced arbic to be into english but after i upload the file it still the same old file
no replace happen

is it the right file i change to change the validation

Comment: I would expect to find the validation error messages in the Models `Model.php` file. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#message It definitely isn't in `/app/tmp`, though.

Comment: I suggest to take a look on /app/view/elements folder

Comment: If the form uses a jQuery plugin for validation it's possible that the messages are coming from JavaScript.

Comment: i looked at them didn't found but in javascript i got this good but dont find messages
 "
function login(siteUrl){ 
 $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  data: $('#FlipLoginForm').serialize(), 
  url: siteUrl+'/flips/login',
  beforeSend: function(){
   $('#commnetResult_login').hide();
   $('#ajaxLoading_login').show(); 
  },
  success:function(result){   
   $('#ajaxLoading_login').hide();
   $('#commnetResult_login').html(result).show();
   if($('#loginrstatus').val()=='done'){      
    window.location=siteUrl+'/flips/display';
   }
  }
 });
} "

Comment: Few questions: 

(1) Please include a copy of the code where the validation message is set (this will tell us if the validation message was written in arabic or if it's currently being translated in arabic)

(2) You mention "the form uses jquery", are you saying the form is submitted through an AJAX request and validation message shown via jQuery?

(3) What kind of translations do you see at app/locale/ ?

Comment: yes the messages were in arabic now show symbols.heres the link when want subcribe. here the link http://www.kalaman-nas.com/flips/display/    I think as the file in app/locale there's file .po but changed arabic to english & no use

Answer (score 0):

Look for the files in `APP/locale`. (read more about this at http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Common-Tasks-With-CakePHP/Internationalization-Localization.html )

Also, you may need to use something like [poedit](http://www.poedit.net/) to edit the .po files if they did it the correct way. This means that you would need to add a new translation file for english. I would not recommend putting the english over the arabic, it could cause potential problems.

Comment: I did try to change the arabic messages into english no use  here the link http://www.kalaman-nas.com/flips/display/

Comment: Are you changing the locale correctly? http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html#localization-in-cakephp Have you setup the content so it switches to the english version of the content too?

Comment: thanks dear chuck burgess  & jrace & all who try helped me.It work now I did edit the default.po & translated the arabic messages into english. in app/local then I should delete the files on this bath app/tmp/cache/persistent .there were like temp files & it cached files on it. as chuck said better use poedit softwear. thanks